# Can I catch element on click if is already used in Wordpress Plugin mmenu?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I need to catch if element is clicked in javascript function, but element class is already used in plugin named "mmenu" on showing hidden header content. Is that event possible, or I need to change implementation without using plugin ?

Element I use in HTML :

```
 <a class="custom-search-mobile" id="mobile-nav-toggle" aria-label="Toggle mobile menu"><span class="fas fa-bars"></span></a>
```

function on find out if element is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.custom-search-mobile').on('click', function (event) {

            console.log("it is clicked!!!!!!");
    });
});
```

Screen of plugin, where I use my CLASS :

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what element was clicked

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.custom-search-mobile').on('click', function (event) {
        var el = $(this)
        console.log(el);
        //manipulate with element
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but problem is, that button execute plugin work and ignore that function

Comment: add another class then. Element can have several classes

Comment: What exactly you want? I dont get what is the issue

Comment: problem is that element I was clicking on is used in wordpress plugin on showing some hidden content,, and I need to catch if that button is clicked... but it is ignored my javascript ... only plugin is called after click

Comment: can you add `onclick="alert('im clicked')` to your element and see if it displaying the alert?

Comment: unfortunatelly, alert is not showing.. probably I can`t use class on working with plugin and also catch it by Javascript